# Masonry Grid post excerpt showing visual composer code?

Tags: wordpress, wrapper, masonry, visual-composer

See screenshot for example. When using a Masonry Grid, the excerpt is showing visual composer code wrappers for the body text. How can I strip out the Visual Composer code in this situation?

Thanks :)

http://forums.artbees.net/uploads/default/original/2X/7/78b00311d50685dd2abcffcf2ae8af9989bcd471.png

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The post excerpt was being automatically generated from the post content meaning it would include the Visual Composer code. By turning Excerpt on in the Screen Options on the Edit Post page, I can manually set an excerpt of my choosing. Winning :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Change the Editor temporally to classic modus [change editor modus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqLrw.png) and add More read Tag () to the text position wherever you want. Now, will WordPress split your post text in de the overview grid also if you use the VC. See screenshots. [add "read more" tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4oP3.png)